# How to raise an ActiveRecord::Rollback exception and return a value together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions, rollback

I have a model that uses a `acts_as_nested_set` fork, and I've added a method to the model to save the model and move the node into the set in one transaction. This method calls a validation method to make sure the move is valid, which returns true or false. If the validation fails, I want my save method to raise `ActiveRecord::Rollback` to rollback the transaction, but also return false to the caller.

My model looks like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_nested_set :dependent => :destroy, :scope => :journal

  def save_with_place_in_set(parent_id)
    Category.transaction do
      return false if !save_without_place_in_set

      if !validate_move parent_id
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback and return false
      else
        place_in_nested_set parent_id
        return true
      end
    end
  end

  alias_method_chain :save, :place_in_set

  def validate_move(parent_id)
    # return true or false if the move is valid
    # ...
  end

  def place_in_nested_set(parent_id)
    # place the node in the correct place in the set
    # ...
  end
end
```

However, when I call save in a situation that would fail, the transaction is rolled back but the function returns `nil`:

```
>> c = Category.new(:name => "test") 
=> #<Category id: nil, name: "test" parent_id: nil, lft: nil, rgt: nil>
>> c.save_with_place_in_set 47
=> nil
>> c.errors.full_messages
=> ["The specified parent is invalid"]
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could store the value you want returned from the function in a variable and return that outside the transaction block. E.g.

```
  def save_with_place_in_set(parent_id)
    return_value = false
    Category.transaction do
      if !save_without_place_in_set
        return_value = false
      elsif !validate_move parent_id
        return_value = false
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      else
        place_in_nested_set parent_id
        return_value = true
      end
    end
    return return_value
  end
```

I've set the return_value to false initially as the only other way you can get out of that transaction block is if one of the other methods raises `ActiveRecord::Rollback` I believe.

Comment: THANK YOU! Still valid in Rails 3.2.8. It wasn't clear to me from the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Rollback.html) that `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` jumps to the line after the end of the transaction.  It looked like it was just falling through, as though the Rollback didn't actually interrupt program flow at all.

Answer (score 16):

Because the `ActiveRecord::Rollback` exception is handled, but not re-raised by `ActiveRecord::Transaction`, I could move my return out of the transaction block, and thus return a value after the transaction is rolled back.

With a little refactoring:

```
def save_with_place_in_set(parent_id = nil)
  Category.transaction do
    return false if !save_without_place_in_set
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if !validate_move parent_id

    place_in_nested_set parent_id
    return true
  end

  return false
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it may be a little late, but i ran into the same problem and just found out, that within a transaction block you can simply raise an Exception and rescue that one...Rails implicitly rollbacks the whole transaction. So there is no need for ActiveRecord::Rollback.

For example:

```
def create
  begin
    Model.transaction do
      # using create! will cause Exception on validation errors
      record = Model.create!({name: nil})
      check_something_afterwards(record)
      return true
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e.message
    return false
  end
end

def check_something_afterwards(record)
  # just for demonstration purpose
  raise Exception, "name is missing" if record.name.nil?
end
```

I'm working with Rails 3.2.15 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: Apparently, ActiveRecord::Rollback is the only exception not transmitted outside the block.